# Copy files within directory and change filename

Tags: java, file

I have a program that is supposed to rename all files within an entire folder (with sub-folders) to a temporary file name, copy those to a different directory, then change the temp filename back to the original filename. During this process I would like to keep all folder names the same. When I run the code below, all it does is change the name of the top-level folders in the path that i specify:

```
package shortenFilenames;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class shortenFilenameClass 
{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            String absolutePathLocal = "C:\\Users\\talain\\Desktop\\marketingOriginal"; //original files
            String absolutePathOnedrive= "C:\\Users\\talain\\Desktop\\fakeOnedrive"; //path to onedrive

            File local = new File(absolutePathLocal);
            File onedrive = new File(absolutePathOnedrive);

            File[] filesInDir = local.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < filesInDir.length; i++) 
            {
                    String name = filesInDir[i].getName();
                    System.out.println(name);
                    String newName = String.valueOf(i);

                    File oldPath = new File(absolutePathLocal + "\\" + newName);
                    System.out.println("oldPath: " + oldPath);
                    filesInDir[i].renameTo(new File(oldPath.toString()));

                    File newPath = new File(absolutePathOnedrive + "\\" + newName);
                    copyFileUsingJava7Files(oldPath, newPath);

                    newPath.renameTo(new File(newPath.toString()));

                   System.out.println("renamed: " + name + "to: " + newName + ", copied to one drive, and changed back to original name");

            }
        }   

        private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
            Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
        }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to change the name of the temp files when copying then change the name back to the original name... why not simply copy all the files in the local path to the one drive path without changing the names?

Comment: Because some files I attempt to copy over have filenames that are too long, and file explorer does not allow me to copy them.

Comment: I've never heard of a file explorer that prevents copying because the name is long !!!! what file explorer is that ? why didn't it allow them ? what error message did you get when trying to copy them ?

Comment: **File oldPath = new File(absolutePathLocal + "\\" + newName);** where **newName** really is **String newName = String.valueOf(i);**, meaning you are failing to provide the **format** of the file. You might want to have a look in that matter too

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following and it copied whatever files were in the first path into the second path. If it fails for you, show me the error output.

```
for(int i = 0; i < filesInDir.length; i++) 
{
    String name = filesInDir[i].getName();
    System.out.println(name);
    Files.copy(new File(absolutePathLocal + "\\" + name).toPath(),new File(absolutePathOnedrive + "\\" + name).toPath());
}
```

Your code also assumes that those directories already exist on your system otherwise you will run into a FileNotFound exception.